# Processing on Java error on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, processing

I got this error message in the console when I tried to run, I just switched laptops and I've wiped my old one. This project has always been stored in a USB so I use that to run it on my new laptop. (So I had to re-download all the applications), I need this to fix so bad due to its my project for class and I haven't record it and I'm supposed to do that and I don't want to fail the class please could u help thank u:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/QuitHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3119)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3260)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3246)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2065)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10751)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10548)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10530)
    at robothead.Robothead.main(Robothead.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 9 more
```

---

I at first download JDK 10 and I read it only works with JDK 8 so I download that and delete JDK 10 in hopes that stuff will return back to normal and it does not works. Also the project, I did it in java oxygen and I downloaded photon on my new laptop and click on the yes I want to convert the files thing so I decided to make a new workspace and copy paste the code but still got that error?Before it was MacBook Air and I switch to the MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up a lot of things.

The basic problem is that starting with Java 9 oracle made changes that lead to such errors ( see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-C86F7403-7D7C-456F-8873-18C7F1BEDE2F).

So, in order to get this to work, you have to ensure that Java 8 is used. And that your Java 10 installation was really, fully removed. You should then check your eclipse settings to also ensure that it is pointing to Java 8.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! But how do I  check my eclipse settings to also ensure that it is pointing to Java 8?

Comment: @StephanieHalim Don't be afraid to google. Doing a search of something like "eclipse check java version" will return a ton of results. I'd recommend trying those results out and posting a new question if you still can't get it figured out. Good luck!

Comment: Glad you found a solution!